# Is a Thread Safe field of TThread itself thread safe?

Tags: delphi, thread-safety, delphi-xe2

in this code :

```
TMyClass = class(TThread)
public
  FInputBuffer     : TThreadedQueue<TBytes>;
protected
  procedure Execute; override;
end;
```

Does use (in TMyClass and in other class) of FInputBuffer is Thread Safe ?

EDIT:

sample use : in TMyClass :

```
procedure TMyClass.Execute;
var x     :TBytes;
begin
  inherited;
  FInputBuffer:= TThreadedQueue<TBytes>.Create;
  while not Terminated do begin
    if FInputBuffer.QueueSize > 0 then begin
      x:= FInputBuffer.PopItem;
      //some code to use x
    end;
  end;
  FInputBuffer.Free;
end;
```

In Other class :

```
var MyClass :TMyClass ;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var x :TBytes;
begin
  //set x
  MyClass.FInputBuffer.PushItem(x);
end;
```

Comment: 1. You have to define what you mean by threadsafe. There are lots of ways to interpret that term. 2. You did not show your other code so even if we knew what you meant by threadsafe, we could hardly judge whether or not the other code meets that requirement.

Comment: One rule for me: a public field is **never** threadsafe, because of the public write access

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `FInputBuffer` is **created in the thread constructor** before the thread begins running, and is **freed in the thread destructor** after the thread has finished running, then yes, access to it from other threads is thread-safe while the `TMyClass` object is still alive, because `TThreadedQueue` provides its own thread-safety for its inner content.  What you have shown is a perfectly valid use of a multi-threaded queue, provided the `MyClass` variable is valid at the time `btn1Click()` is called.

However, if `FInputBuffer` is **created inside of `Execute()`**, then it is **not** thread-safe, because `btn1Click()` might try to access the queue before the thread has started running, before `FInputBuffer` has been created.  That is why you need to create `FInputBuffer` in the constructor instead, eg:

```
TMyClass = class(TThread)
public
  FInputBuffer: TThreadedQueue<TBytes>;
  constructor Create(ACreateSuspended: Boolean); override;
  destructor Destroy; override;
protected
  procedure Execute; override;
end;

constructor TMyClass.Create(ACreateSuspended: Boolean);
begin
  inherited;
  FInputBuffer := TThreadedQueue<TBytes>.Create;
end;

destructor TMyClass.Destroy;
begin
  FInputBuffer.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyClass.Execute;
var
  x: TBytes;
begin
  while not Terminated do begin
    if FInputBuffer.QueueSize > 0 then begin
      x := FInputBuffer.PopItem;
      // some code to use x
    end;
  end;
end;
```

If you want to create `FInputBuffer` inside of `Execute()`, then thread should expose a flag/signal that gets set after `FInputBuffer` has actually been created, and then no other code should attempt to access `FInputBuffer` until that flag/signal has been set. The code that creates the thread instance should wait for that flag/signal before returning control back to the rest of the code, eg:

```
TMyClass = class(TThread)
public
  FInputBuffer: TThreadedQueue<TBytes>;
  FInputBufferCreated: TEvent;
  constructor Create(ACreateSuspended: Boolean); override;
  destructor Destroy; override;
protected
  procedure Execute; override;
  procedure DoTerminate; override;
end;

constructor TMyClass.Create(ACreateSuspended: Boolean);
begin
  inherited;
  FInputBufferCreated := TEvent.Create(nil, True, False, '');
end;

destructor TMyClass.Destroy;
begin
  FInputBufferCreated.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyClass.Execute;
var
  x: TBytes;
begin
  FInputBuffer := TThreadedQueue<TBytes>.Create;
  FInputBufferCreated.SetEvent;

  while not Terminated do begin
    if FInputBuffer.QueueSize > 0 then begin
      x := FInputBuffer.PopItem;
      // some code to use x
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyClass.DoTerminate;
begin
  if FInputBufferCreated <> nil then
    FInputBufferCreated.ResetEvent;
  FreeAndNil(FInputBuffer);
  inherited;
end;
```

.

```
var
  MyClass: TMyClass = nil;

procedure TForm1.StartBufferThread;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  MyClass := TMyClass.Create(False);
  if MyClass.FInputBufferCreated.WaitFor(2500) <> wrSignaled then
  begin
    MyClass.Terminate;
    MyClass.WaitFor;
    FreeAndNil(MyClass);
    raise Exception.Create('MyClass.FInputBuffer not created after 2.5 seconds!');
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  x: TBytes;
begin
  //set x
  if MyClass <> nil then
    MyClass.FInputBuffer.PushItem(x);
end;
```